# Synchronizing a buffer in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

So I'm new to both C# and working with multiple threads. I got this application which has 2 classes, writer and reader which both have a reference to my CharacterBuffer class. So I input a string to the program, and the writer should read the chracters to the buffer, and the reader read from the buffer, all synchronized. This is the buffer class:

```
public class CharacterBuffer
{
    private  static object Lock = new object();
    private Queue result;

    public CharacterBuffer()
    {
        result = new Queue();
        lock (result);
    }

    public void addChar(char c)
    {
        result.Enqueue(c);
        Monitor.PulseAll(result);
    }

    public char readChar()
    {
        Monitor.Wait(result);
        return (char) result.Dequeue();
    }
}
```

So what I think I am doing is first I declare the queue and put a lock unto it. So when the reader calls readChar() it will have to wait until the writer has called addChar(char c). But whenever I start the reader and writer thread, it instantly throws an exception`'System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

Obviosuly I'm doing something wrong. I have searched for an answer and it seems that the code block calling Monitor have to make all the calls in the same block. Beacuse in this case, my separate threads are calling it instead of the Buffer itself. So the question is; what to do instead?

Comment: Your declaring a lock object but then locking the `result`. Your lock should be on `Lock`. Your also not using `lock()` correcly.

Comment: why not ```ConcurrentQueue<T>``` ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Starting from scratch. :)

Comment: https://pragmaticdevs.wordpress.com/2015/10/15/producer-consumer-problem-using-locks-in-c-net/

Comment: @vtortola: this is exactly what I have proposed to do in my answer (see second code fragment)

Comment: If you insist on writing your own concurrent queue, at least use `Queue<T>` instead of `Queue`. And learn multi-threading - it's a serious subject, not something you can blunder around and hope for the best. http://www.albahari.com/threading/ is a great primer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are concerned about queue modified in multiple threads, please use following code:

```
public class CharacterBuffer
{
    private object padlock = new object();
    private Queue result = new Queue();

    public void AddChar(char c)
    {
        // lock the padlock so that no two threads try to read/write at the same time
        lock (padlock)
        {
            result.Enqueue(c);
        }
    }

    public char ReadChar()
    {
        // lock the padlock so that no two threads try to read/write at the same time
        lock (padlock)
        {
            return (char) result.Dequeue();
        }
    }
}
```

If you are willing to implement blocking queue and do signalling so that reader waits for writer to put something in queue, use this code:

```
public class CharacterBuffer
{
    private object padlock = new object();
    private Queue result = new Queue();

    public void AddChar(char c)
    {
        // lock the padlock so that no two threads try to read/write at the same time
        lock (padlock)
        {
            result.Enqueue(c);
            if (result.Count == 1)
            {
                // wake up any blocked dequeue
                Monitor.PulseAll(padlock);
            }
        }
    }

    public char ReadChar()
    {
        // lock the padlock so that no two threads tries to read/write at the same time
        lock (padlock)
        {
            // block the thread and wait until there is something in the queue
            while (result.Count == 0)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(padlock);
            }

            return (char) result.Dequeue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So in your first code example lock(Lock) basicly works like a toggle switch? I'm not sure I understand; Say that writerThread calls addChar first, before the readerThread.  then won't it be blocked?

Comment: I don't think two threads can call to the ctor of the same instance at the same time :)

Comment: @vtortola: it is not about calling constructor two times, is is about calling AddChar or ReadChar before constructor has finished.

Comment: @snickesnack: Only one thread can have a lock on padlock object at any given time. This ensures that read/write is not called in parallel that would break `Queue` internal state, but instead they are called sequentially.

Comment: @KasparsOzols how can you call an instance method before the instance is constructed in this case?

Comment: Ah! ´Then I understand! :)

Comment: @vtortola: in this case you are probably right - this is very unlikely scenario. Removed lock & constructor completely.

Comment: @snickesnack Both `Monitor.Wait` and `Monitor.Pulse` will release the lock until they are finished. They would be quite worthless otherwise - they only work inside of a lock (for obvious reasons), and if they didn't exit the lock, noöne could signal them, since `Monitor` (used by `lock` as well) is an exclusive lock.

Answer (score 2):

> So the question is: what to do instead?

Use [pipeline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963548.aspx)!

```
var buffer = new BlockingCollection<string>();

// Start reading thread
var readTask = Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        // Read data from source and put to buffer
        foreach (var data in source)
        {
            buffer.Add(data);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // Signal the end of the data
        buffer.CompleteAdding();
    }
});

// Start writing thread
var writeTask = Task.Run(() =>
{
    foreach (string data in buffer.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        // Process data
    }
});

Task.WaitAll(readTask, writeTask);
```

There is no need for manual locking. Just use the modern approaches that simplify programming and prevent mistakes.

Comment: I guess he is planning to use threads not tasks. Tasks do provide good abstraction for threads and are easier to work with but provide less control.

Comment: @AmmarSalman - Key in this approach are not tasks (they are easy to replace to threads) but BlockingCollection and pipelining.

Comment: Ah I get it. I guess he is also trying to implement the blocking queue manually.

Comment: @AmmarSalman - Yes, of course. However, please note that I highlighted the quote that answered: "what to do **instead**".

Comment: Convinced me. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply lock like here:

```
public class CharacterBuffer
{
    private  static object Lock = new object();
    private Queue result;

    public CharacterBuffer()
    {
        result = new Queue();

    }

    public void addChar(char c)
    {
        lock(Lock)
        {
          result.Enqueue(c);
          Monitor.PulseAll(result);
        }
    }

    public char readChar()
    {
        lock(Lock)
        {
             return (char) result.Dequeue();
        }
    }
}
```

lock is a syntactic sugar that enter a critical session in the { part, and leave it in the } ( or if the code exit somehow the block).

Answer (score 0):

You're implementing a blocking queue this way. In your constructor you're locking the queue itself which is wrong. The locking should be done when you enqueue or dequeue (put character or remove character) along with the monitoring. I would do something similar to:

```
public class CharacterBuffer
{
    private  static object Lock = new object();
    private Queue result;

    public CharacterBuffer()
    {
        result = new Queue();
        //lock (result);  <-- this is WRONG
    }

    public void addChar(char c)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(Lock){
                result.Enqueue(c);
        }
        Monitor.Pulse(Lock);
    }

    public char readChar()
    {
        char c;
        Monitor.Wait(result);
        Monitor.Enter(Lock){
            c = (char)result.Deqeueue(); 
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Please *NOTE* this code is not revised. It should just give you a clue