# Process files concurrently and asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, concurrency, parallel-processing

Looking for some help with best practices on creating a potentially multi-threaded asynchronous application. This application will look through several directories for a certain pattern (configurable per directory).  For all of the files it finds in that directory, it will kick off an asynchronous operation for each file (read/write, DB operations, API calls, etc). The directories themselves should be processed concurrently as they are unrelated to each other.

It's my understanding that `Task` may not always execute on a separate thread.  Because this application may have to handle dozens to hundreds of files at any one time, I want to make sure I am maximizing throughput of the application. It's also worth noting that there may or may not be files in the directory when this application runs.

Is simply using `Task` enough to accomplish this and achieve maximum throughput, or is there some combination of `Parallel.ForEach` with an asynchronous function that would be better?  Below is what I have created so far just as a test to see and it looks like it's processing 1 directory at a time on the same thread.

**Main**

```
class Program {
    static IEnumerable<DirectoryConfig> GetDirectoryConfigs() {
        return new DirectoryConfig[] {
            new DirectoryConfig {
                DirectoryPath = @"PATH_1",
                Token = "*",
                FileProcessor = new FileProcessor()
            },
            new DirectoryConfig {
                DirectoryPath = @"PATH_2",
                Token = "*",
                FileProcessor = new FileProcessor()
            }
        };
    }
    static async Task Main(string[] args) {
        IEnumerable<DirectoryConfig> directoryConfigs = GetDirectoryConfigs();

        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach(DirectoryConfig config in directoryConfigs) {
            Console.WriteLine("Processing directory {0}", config.DirectoryPath);

            tasks.Add(new DirectoryMonitor().ProcessDirectoryAsync(config));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

**DirectoryMonitor**

```
class DirectoryMonitor {
    public Task ProcessDirectoryAsync(DirectoryConfig config) {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(config.DirectoryPath, config.Token)) {
            tasks.Add(config.FileProcessor.ProcessAsync(file));
        }

        return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

**FileProcessor**

```
class FileProcessor : IFileProcessor {
    public async Task ProcessAsync(string file) {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
        Console.WriteLine("Processing file {0} on thread {1}", fileName,
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file)) {
            int lineNumber = 0;
            while(!reader.EndOfStream) {
                Console.WriteLine("Reading line {0} of file {1}", ++lineNumber, fileName);
                string line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

                await DoAsyncWork(line);
            }
        }
    }

    private Task DoAsyncWork(string line) {
        return Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tasks and threads are different things. Sure, you can queue up tasks using the threadpool which will run multiple tasks in parallel, but other than that, using tasks does not in any way, shape, or form, imply anything about threads.

Comment: You may stuck with the drive's bandwidth. As a result, a large number of tasks will wait aimlessly for data from drive. | I would use pipelines, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/40609081/5045688

Comment: You can offload the directory traversal/search to threadpool using `Task.Run` and then write each filepath to a `Pipeline` and have a separate thread read off of the `Pipeline` and do the processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of job a powerful tool you could use is the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library. With this tool you can create a processing pipeline consisting of many linked blocks, with the data flowing from the first block to the last (circles and meshes are also possible).

The advantages of this approach are:

1. You get data-parallelism on top of task-parallelism. All blocks are working concurrently and independently from each other.
2. You can configure optimally the level of concurrency (a.k.a. degree of parallelism) of each heterogeneous operation. For example doing API calls may be highly parallelizable, while reading from the hard disk may be not parallelizable at all.
3. You get advanced options out of the box (`BoundedCapacity`, `CancellationToken` and others).
4. You get built-in support for both synchronous and asynchronous delegates.

Below is how you could rewrite your original code in TPL Dataflow terms. Three blocks are used, two [`TransformManyBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformmanyblock-2)s and one [`ActionBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1).

```
var directoryBlock = new TransformManyBlock<DirectoryConfig, string>(config =>
{
    return Directory.GetFiles(config.DirectoryPath, config.Token);
});

var fileBlock = new TransformManyBlock<string, string>(filePath =>
{
    return File.ReadLines(filePath);
});

var lineBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(async line =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4
});

directoryBlock.LinkTo(fileBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
fileBlock.LinkTo(lineBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

foreach (DirectoryConfig config in GetDirectoryConfigs())
    await directoryBlock.SendAsync(config);

directoryBlock.Complete();
await lineBlock.Completion;
```

This example is not very good since all the work is done by the last block (the `lineBlock`), and the first two blocks are doing essentially nothing. It is also not memory-efficient since all lines of all files of all directories will soon become queued in the input buffer of the `ActionBlock`, unless processing the lines happens to be faster than reading them from the disk. You'll need to configure the blocks with [`BoundedCapacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.boundedcapacity) to solve this problem.

This example also fails to demonstrate how you could have different blocks for different types of files, and link the `directoryBlock` to all of them using a different filtering predicate for each link:

```
directoryBlock.LinkTo(csvBlock, filePath => Path.GetExtension(filePath) == "csv");
directoryBlock.LinkTo(xlsBlock, filePath => Path.GetExtension(filePath) == "xls");
directoryBlock.LinkTo(generalFileBlock); // Anything that is neither csv nor xls
```

There are also other types of blocks you could use, like the [`TransformBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformblock-2) and the [`BatchBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.batchblock-1). The TPL Dataflow is based on the Task Parallel Library (TPL), and it is essentially a high level task-generator that creates and controls the lifecycle of the tasks needed in order to process a workload of given type, based on declarative configuration. It is built-in the .NET Core, and available as a [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/) for .NET Framework.

Comment: +1 for the most complete answer.  I am going to give this a try today with my little test environment (2 directories each with 100 files at 1MB each).

Comment: Marking this as the answer.  I had to change the logic slightly to work with my asyncronous `IFileProcessor`, but overall much better than what I had.  Thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: @Kyle my pleasure! Just a note: having a too granular workload may affect the performance of your app. For example if you are processing a huge number of file-lines, and the processing of each line is too lightweight, then you may get a significant overhead by passing all these lines from block to block. In that case you could consider chunkifying your workload (the `BatchBlock` is great at doing that), and pass the lines around in batches (arrays) of, say, 100 lines per batch. Then inside each block perform a loop to process or transform each individual line.

Answer (score 0):

Tasks do indeed not necessarily run on different threads, but the default scheduler and thread pool will do a pretty good job of processing work as fast as possible.  You can tweak the defaults (see the second link below), but it’s unlikely (though possible) you will improve the outcome that way. There’s usually little point e.g. running 100s of concurrent threads if your CPU can only execute say 4 operations truly concurrently.

Then there could be contention for the storage device, especially if it’s a spinning disk, which might affect things significantly. Depending on the size of the files it might be more performant to read the whole file in one go rather than stream it in line by line.

Lastly, as no doubt others will also say: try different options and measure. There are a lot of variables (hardware, directory structure, file sizes, the type/complexity/duration of processing you are doing on each file) that could all affect performance, and it’s likely only measuring will determine the best option.

Some reading for further pointers:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-threading-best-practices

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool#thread-pool-characteristics