# Catching exceptions when using async/await and ContinueWith

Tags: c#, exception, task-parallel-library

I'm building a generic abstract class (.NET Framework 4.6.1) that will get items from a work queue (Amazon SQS in this case but ultimately the source is unimportant) and do some sort of processing on each item. I have abstract methods declared where the inheritors are supposed to override in order to do their work. I want to be able to execute these methods in parallel using Tasks and then to raise events to indicate processing was successful or not. This is a stripped-down version of what I have. The goal is to catch and unhandled exceptions thrown in `ProcessReceivedItemAsync` by the derived class and then raise an event.

```
public class SimpleSqsItemProcessor<T> : IItemProcessor<T>
{
    public event EventHandler<SqsMessageEventArgs<T>> ProcessingCompleted;
    public event EventHandler<SqsMessageProcessingFailedEventArgs<T>> ProcessingFailed;

    // ProcessingStatus is an enum with values like "Success", "Failure", etc
    public abstract Task<ProcessingStatus> ProcessReceivedItemAsync(SqsWrapper<T> item);

    public async Task<int> ProcessNextSetAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // SqsWrapper has SQS message metadata, like Message ID, receipt handle, etc
        Queue<SqsWrapper<T>> items = await GetFromSqs();
        int count = 0;
        if (items.Count == 0)
            return count;

        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(items.Count);
        while (items.Count > 0)
        {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                items.Clear();
                return count;
            }

            SqsWrapper<T> next = items.Dequeue();
            count += 1;

            tasks.Add(ProcessReceivedItemAsync(next).ContinueWith(async t =>
            {
                try
                {
                    ProcessingStatus status = await t;

                    if (status == ProcessingStatus.Success)
                        // this method simply deletes from SQS
                        await _successHandler.HandleSuccessAsync(next);

                    // this method invokes the ProcessingCompleted event
                    OnProcessingCompleted(next);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // this method invokes the ProcessingFailed event
                    OnProcessingFailed(next, ex);
                }
            }));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        return count;
    }
}
```

Then I can make a derived class like so:

```
public class MyProcessor : SimpleSqsItemProcessor<MyObject>
{
    public override Task<ProcessingStatus> ProcessReceivedItemAsync(SqsWrapper<MyObject> item)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int i = rnd.Next(0, 1);
        if (i == 0)
            throw new Exception("OH NOES!");
        return Task.FromResult(ProcessingStatus.Success);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when debugging, we never enter the catch block in `ProcessNextSetAsync` when an exception gets thrown, because I thought that exceptions get triggered when you `await` a Task. Even if I wrap the `await Task.WhenAll` statement in a try-catch, my break point in the catch block doesn't get hit. Instead the "OH NOES!" exception bubbles up.

Note that I cannot change the return type of the `ProcessReceivedItemAsync` method to be the item itself, as the interface I'm implementing is old code and long-established. I know I could individually `await` those method calls, but I want those all to run in parallel. I've used this technique before when my antecedent Task didn't throw any exceptions, but this is the first time I'm doing it like this. I want to ensure that the `ProcessingFailed` event gets raised, so I don't want to assume that the derived classes are going to do it

Questions:

1. Where do I catch the exception being thrown by the derived class?
2. How can I ensure that I can associate the object being processed with the exception being thrown?

Thanks in advance for any insight you can offer.

Comment: Just don't use `ContinueWith` at all.  It's extremely difficult to use properly.  It's virtually always better to use `await` to add continuations to tasks instead.  When you mix and match the two it's *even worse*, and makes creating correct code *very* hard, and makes understanding that code hard even when it functions properly.

Comment: @Servy Yeah I've definitely read that before, but awaiting each individual method call is the same as running them all serially with the only difference being that the main thread isn't blocked.

Comment: Then you create a new method to generate a task that represents the operation you want to have a `Task` for.  You don't need to try to fit your entire program into one method.

Comment: Have you considered using an existing processing library, like the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) for example, instead of building your own processing system from scratch?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I haven't heard of this library before. I'll definitely take a look. Thanks!

Comment: It is a powerful and feature-rich library, and also robust and mature (it is as old as the TPL itself), and reasonably efficient. Its drawbacks are that it's not fluent like [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq), not easily extensible, and doesn't take advantage of the newer `ValueTask` technology. Probably none of them is going to affect you. You can find an example of using it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602684/c-sharp-process-files-concurrently-and-asynchronously/62613098#62613098).