# Run multiple tasks in semiparallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task

I have a list of tasks where each task has two subtasks. I only want to start the next task after the previous task has completed the first subtask. (the first subtask calls about 1000 times to a single http api and it seems that it goes down if/throttles if I call it "too much", the second task is a fairly long-running cpu-bound task).

My idea has been similar to the following example code (in the real case the list of task grows to a count of at least 300):

```
class Program
{
    

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new TestMultiTask();
        await test.TestListOfTasks();
        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
} 

public class TestMultiTask
{
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; private set; }
    public async Task TestListOfTasks()
    {
        Tasks = new List<Task>();
        Tasks.Add(Task2SubTask(new Progress<MyProgress>(ReportProgress), 0));
        await Task.WhenAll(Tasks);
        Console.WriteLine("Finished TestListOfTasks");
    }

    private void ReportProgress(MyProgress obj)
    {
        if (obj.ProgressNo < 10)
        {
            Tasks.Add(Task2SubTask(new Progress<MyProgress>(ReportProgress), obj.ProgressNo + 1));
        }
    }

    private async Task Task2SubTask(IProgress<MyProgress> progress, int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Task {i}, started.");
        await Task.Delay(700); // simulating getting data from web api (abt- 1000 calls)
        Console.WriteLine($"Task {i}, completed subtask 1."); 
        progress.Report(new MyProgress() { Task1Done = true, ProgressNo = i }); // now the next task can start getting data form web api.
        await Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(1000)); // Process the data collected (in this task) from the web api
        Console.WriteLine($"Task {i} done."); // return processed data.
    }

}
```

This has however at least one flaw - the `Program.Main` continues as soon as the first task in the list is done, even if the list is expanded.
Does anyone know of a smarter way of doing this? (Maybe a totally different approach?)

EDIT:
Thanks for the comments.. now I tried to comment the code to make it more clear.

Comment: I am a little confused by the tasks and subtasks here. So you need to call an API 1000 times, then after each call complete a CPU bound workload ?

Comment: What I understand from your Question (tell me if wrong): SubTask1 collects data from some API, SubTask2 processes that data. These two, you have "chunks" of which you thought was a good idea to create a "parent" Task for. Is that correct?

Comment: Have you considered the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library? It allows to define a pipeline consisting of multiple blocks, each one associated with a specific kind of task and configured independently, and then feed the pipeline with messages (for example URLs) that are processed along the way. So you get both task parallelism and data parallelism. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602684/c-sharp-process-files-concurrently-and-asynchronously/62613098#62613098) is a usage example.

Comment: This sound to me more like a pipeline thing. You need one step that sequentially calls the API for one "chunk", then the respective result should go to a second step, where it is processed. Maybe DataFlow is for you?

Comment: @TheGeneral - I tried to comment to make it a bit more easy to understand.

Comment: Like others have stated, seem like an easy job for a couple of TPL DataFlow blocks, where you can control the degrees of parallelism and will work well with IO and CPU bound workloads.

Comment: You can do foreach loop over your tasks and do `await task.FirstPart();` but then not await `task.SecondPart()` (instead adding it to some list for later awaiting with `Task.WhenAll`, or using `ContinueWith` to observe its result).

Comment: Thanks you all. TPL Dataflow sounds like a good way and @Evk 's seems like simple solution that might do the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, thanks for the many comments. I tried out @Evk 's proposal and ended up with the following code...

```
public class TestMultiTask2
{
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; private set; }
    public async Task TestListOfTasks()
    {
        var workers = new List<Worker>();
        var crunchingTasks = new List<Task>();
        var n = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            var w = new Worker(i);
            workers.Add(w);
            await w.GetDataAsync(new Progress<MyProgress>(ReportProgress));
            crunchingTasks.Add(w.CrunchData(new Progress<MyProgress>(ReportProgress)));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(crunchingTasks);
        Console.WriteLine($"Worker 0 data: {string.Join(", ", workers[0].Datas)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Worker {n-1} data: {string.Join(", ", workers[n-1].Datas)}");
        Console.WriteLine("Finished TestListOfTasks");
    }

    private void ReportProgress(MyProgress obj)
    {
        if (obj.Task2Started)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Task no. {obj.TaskNo} has started chrunching data: {obj.Task2Started}");
        }
        else if(obj.Task2Done)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Task no. {obj.TaskNo} has finished chrunching data: {obj.Task2Done}");
        }
        else if (obj.Task1Done)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Task no. {obj.TaskNo} has finished getting data: {obj.Task1Done}"); 
        }
    }


}

public class MyProgress
{
    public int TaskNo { get; set; }
    public bool Task1Done { get; set; }
    public bool Task2Done { get; internal set; }
    public bool Task2Started { get; internal set; }
}

public class Worker
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public Worker(int id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }
    public List<int> Datas { get; set; } = new List<int>() { 0, 0, 0 };
    public async Task GetDataAsync(IProgress<MyProgress> progress)
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
        Datas = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
        progress.Report(new MyProgress() { TaskNo = ID, Task1Done = true });
    }

    public async Task CrunchData(IProgress<MyProgress> progress)
    {
        progress.Report(new MyProgress() { TaskNo = ID, Task2Started = true });
        await Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(5000); Datas.Reverse(); });
        progress.Report(new MyProgress() { TaskNo = ID, Task2Done = true });
    }
}
class Program
{


    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new TestMultiTask2();
        await test.TestListOfTasks();
        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```