# Unexpected Parallel.ForEach loop behavior

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

Hi I am trying to mimic multi threading with `Parallel.ForEach` loop. Below is my function:

```
public void PollOnServiceStart()
{
    constants = new ConstantsUtil();
    constants.InitializeConfiguration();

    HashSet<string> newFiles = new HashSet<string>();

    //string serviceName = MetadataDbContext.GetServiceName();

    var dequeuedItems = MetadataDbContext
        .UpdateOdfsServiceEntriesForProcessingOnStart();
    var handlers = Producer.GetParserHandlers(dequeuedItems);

    while (handlers.Any())
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(handlers,
            new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
            handler =>
            {
                Logger.Info($"Started  processing a file remaining in Parallel ForEach");
                handler.Execute();
                Logger.Info($"Enqueing one file for next process");
                dequeuedItems = MetadataDbContext
                    .UpdateOdfsServiceEntriesForProcessingOnPollInterval(1);
                handlers = Producer.GetParserHandlers(dequeuedItems);
            });

        int filesRemovedCount = Producer.RemoveTransferredFiles();
        Logger.Info($"{filesRemovedCount} files removed from {Constants.OUTPUT_FOLDER}");
    }
}
```

So to explain what's going on. The function `UpdateOdfsServiceEntriesForProcessingOnStart()` gets 4 file names (4 because of parallel count) and adds them to a thread safe object called `ParserHandler`. These objects are then put into a list `var handlers`.

My idea here is to loop through this handler list and call the `handler.Execute()`.

`Handler.Execute()` copies files from the network location onto a local drive, parses through the file and creates multiple output files, then sends said files to a network location and updates a DB table.

What I expect in this Parallel For Each loop is that after the `Handler.Execute()` call, `UpdateOdfsServiceEntriesForProcessingOnPollInterval(1)` function will add a new file name from the db table it reads to the dequeued items container which will then be passed as one item to the recreated handler list. In this way, after one file is done executing, a new file will take its place for each parallel loop.

However what happens is that while I do get a new file added it doesn't get executed by the next available thread. Instead what happens is that the parallel for each has to finish executing the first 4 files and then it will pick up the very next file. Meaning, after the first 4 are ran in parallel, only 1 file is ran at a time thereby nullifying the whole point of the parallel looping. The initial files added before all 4 files finish the `Execute()` call are never executed.

IE:

(Start1, Start2, Start3, Start4) all at once. What should happen is something like (End2, Start5), and then (End3, Start6). But what is happening is (End 2, End 3, End 1, End 4), Then Start5. End5. Start6, End6.
Why is this happening?

Because we want to deploy multiple of instances of this service app in a machine, it is not beneficial to have a giant list waiting in queue. This is wasteful as the other app instances wont be able to process things.

Comment: There are better technologies to use here. Possibly TPL Dataflow, or possibly RX, or even possibly mixed a reliable message bus and a dedicated processing service. However its hard to give any recommendations as the topology of the design is unclear and you are focusing on likely the Y of an X/Y problem. if you have a queue of items that need to be serialized and processed with a Max Degree Of Parallelism. My first choice would be a simple `ActionBlock` with a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` and `BoundedCapacity` set to the max number jobs you want in flight at once

Comment: Or if you want a specific answer, you will need to explain the exact nature of `UpdateOdfsServiceEntriesForProcessingOnStart` and `GetParserHandlers` what they do and any further system wide concurrency constraints

Comment: Have you traced out what's happening.  In my experience, what I'd see would be (Start1, Start2, Start3, Start4) all at once, then see something like (End2, Start5), and then (End3, Start6), etc.  As one item of work ends, another immediately starts (but there are still three others running).  In my case, I'd still get 4 units of work happening at all times, but you'd see one end and another immediately start.  It's a little weird, but think about it.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` should not be used when I/O operations are involved, in those cases it's better to use async/wait methods. Overall check Thread Pool and Pipeline design patterns to address your problem.

Comment: I appreciate your willingness to try to improve on [the question you asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66271054/c-sharp-windows-service-takes-forever-to-finish-starting-with-parallel-foreach-l), but frankly this example is not much better. You still haven't provided a [mcve], and the code still has elements that make no sense (such as the reassignment of the `handlers` variable in the `ForEach()` delegate).

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes it should be (Start1, Start2, Start3, Start4) all at once and then turn into something like (End2, Start5), and then (End3, Start6). But what is happening is (End 2, End 3, End 1, End 4), Then Start5. End5. Start6, End6.

Comment: @00110001 I have edited the OP to explain a bit more.

Comment: @WagnerDosAnjos why is it a bad idea to use Parallel.ForEach for I/O operations? By I/O operations, I assume you mean operations involving harddrive writes and reads? Or are you talking about User input?

Comment: There is two kinds of work that you can do asynchronously (roughly speaking), _I/O Bound work_ and _CPU Bound Work_. If you are doing I/O work (like talking to disk drives or web services, then you can take advantage of the natural asynchrony of I/O operations by using Async and await. If you are doing CPU work (complex calculations like doing Ray tracing), then it's best to load up your CPU by dispatching the work to as many cores the processor has. Where the dividing line is can be hard to tell for some workloads. Sometimes it's easy

Comment: @Flydog57 I am new to C# and new to programming I'm still a student. Is there an article that describes the difference between sync and async and which parallel functions they use? What is it about I/O ops that make them suited for async vs non async?

Comment: The `MetadataDbContext` and `Producer` classes are accessed by multiple threads concurrently during the parallel loop. Are they thread-safe?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias They are. The originally ran in a Blocking Collection Producer Consumer parallel thread system

Answer (score 1):

I am writing what should be a long comment as an answer, although it's an awful answer because it doesn't answer the question.

Be aware that parallelizing filesystem operations is unlikely to make them faster, especially if the storage is a classic hard disk. The head of the disk cannot be in N places at the same moment, and if you tell it to do so will just waste most of its time traveling instead of reading or writing.

The best way to overcome the bottleneck imposed by accessing the filesystem is to make sure that there is work for the disk to do at all moments. Don't stop the disk's work to make a computation or to fetch/save data from/to the database. To make this happen you must have multiple workflows running concurrently. One workflow will do entirely I/O with the disk, another workflow will talk continuously with the database, a third workflow will utilize the CPU by doing the one calculation after the other etc. This approach is called task parallelism (doing heterogeneous work in parallel), as opposed with data parallelism (doing homogeneous work in parallel, the speciality of `Parallel.ForEach`). It is also called pipelining, because in order to make all workflows run concurrently you must place intermediate buffers between them, so you create a pipeline with the data flowing from buffer to buffer. Another term used for this kind of operations is producer-consumer pattern, which describes a short pipeline consisting by only two building blocks, with the first being the producer and the second the consumer.

The most powerful tool currently available¹ to create pipelines, is the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library. It offers a variety of "blocks" (pipeline segments) that can be linked with each other, and can cover most scenarios. What you do is that you instantiate the blocks that will compose your pipeline, you configure them, you tell each one what work it should do, you link them together, you feed the first block with the initial raw data that should be processed, and finally `await` for the `Completion` of the last block. You can look at an example of using the TPL Dataflow library [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602684/c-sharp-process-files-concurrently-and-asynchronously/62613098#62613098).

¹ <sub>Available as built-in library in the .NET platform. Powerful third-party tools also exist, like the Akka.NET for example.</sub>